# Google Maps: tiled overlay

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm building a map with particular areas highlighted (with custom polygons), is there a way that I can 'darken out' the rest of the globe using a tiled overlay? This is purely for aesthetics mostly so that the highlighted areas are more prominent.

This is the closest I've found from the API documentation, but it appears to be for v2 and deprecated: 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/tileoverlay-simple.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something similar using [Ground Overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays) in the Maps API V3. You can also darken the map by [Styling](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html) it, though that is the whole map.